# CSS stretchable background with fixed proportions

Tags: html, css

I have div with absolute height and width:

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 300px;">
```

I want to put a background image (width 500px; height 1500px ) to fit the width of the DIV, but i want to let overflow the height of the div. I don't want to loose proportions of my image.

Image is generated dynamically, sometimes is height smallest than a div height. I need to be always cover on width, don't care about height.

Is in CSS some way to do it without need of using javascript?

`background-size: cover` value works only when image height is smaller than div height.

Im finding something like:

```
background-size: 100% default;
```

Comment: Background - size should have worked. It isn't the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try: 

.element {
background-size: cover
}
```

Comment: Cover value works only when image height is smaller than div height. Otherwise it will re-size to image height.